# is there an iUI for the Android

Tags: iphone, android, user-interface

Im developing for both iPhone and Android. For iPhone im using iUI to show what the user interface would look like from a browser. Does anyone know if there is a similar javascript/css library which would allow me to mock up the Android interface?

Comment: How about Titanium (http://www.appcelerator.com/) ? I use it for both iPhone & Android development.

Comment: Im actually using that to do the development on the phones themselves but need an admin page on an ordinary web site that can simulate what the controls would look like on android and iphone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just use iUI. [This guy](http://www.remi-grumeau.com/labs/iui/) has an Android theme for iUI - go to Theme Switcher and select Android to see what it looks like.

Not sure what the license is on the css. You should probably ask him.

Answer (score 2):

> Im developing for both iPhone and
>   Android. For iPhone im using iUI to
>   show what the user interface would
>   look like from a browser.

Hi! Good choice :)

The Android theme for iUI is not perfect to me but you can use it at its current state.
This theme is now part of the iUI official source tree so feel free to grab it using Hg on the Google code project page. Since it's now part of iUI, it's released under New BSD license.

> Does anyone know if there is a similar
>   javascript/css library which would
>   allow me to mock up the Android
>   interface?

http://code.google.com/p/iui/source/browse/#hg/web-app/iui/ext-sandbox/t/android
Have fun :)

> Im actually using that to do the
>   development on the phones themselves
>   but need an admin page on an ordinary
>   web site that can simulate what the
>   controls would look like on android
>   and iphone.

Then you should also dynamically replace all form elements with custom designed divs, for both iPhone and Android.

Remi

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is no Android version, per se - but iUI works just fine. I use it for web-based apps on both Android and iPhone all the time.

jQTouch is also a good solution, but it's considerably less attractive on Android, simply because the page transitions are all geared toward iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the default phonegap (now cordova) app looks alot like an android app. If you want some quick and dirty try that maybe.

Heres a png screen shot:
http://www.thesearethedroids.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/PhoneGap_screen.png

Answer (score 0):

The code associated with this book has the equivalent to iui, more or less:

Pro Android Web Apps
Develop for Android using HTML5, CSS3 & JavaScript

By Damon Oehlman , Sébastien Blanc

http://www.apress.com/programming/css/9781430232766